# ejGrid Hidden columns's header does not hide in syncfusion JS

Tags: syncfusion

I am using **SyncFusion JS ejGrid** in my project.
I am facing strange issue.
I am trying to **hide Primary Key Colum**n in Grid. Column get hide but It's **Header does not hide**.

I am also getting 
"**TypeError: this.model.currentViewData is null**" error constantly.

Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query: Column get hide but It's **Header does not hide**

This issue had been reproduced in the Essential Studio v11.4.0.26 and it can be resolved by referring the **bootstrap.css** before the **ej.widgets.all.css** in your application. It has not been reproduced in the latest version (12.1.0.49) and hence we suggest you to upgrade to the latest version.

Please find the latest JavaScript studio from the below link.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/jsservicepacks

And also specify the Essential Studio version you are using so that we can analyze your issue and provide solution as early as possible.

**Query:TypeError: this.model.currentViewData is null**

Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for your favorable reply. I had not check answer as I already get some work around. Probably SyncFusion have not mention about Visible=true/false in columns to set visibility.